# Attempting to reference a deleted function (copy c'tor)

Tags: c++, initialization, atomic

I got this example of `spinlock` from [Anthony Williams](https://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Concurrency-Action-Second/dp/B082MSBZ68/ref=sr_1_1?adgrpid=48775698450&gclid=Cj0KCQiAw9qOBhC-ARIsAG-rdn4B5ybCticg-RmVkhfAN4GKaN9SOcnYuErJ-R_MiwHJT1-83R79E50aAp53EALw_wcB&hvadid=259087860624&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=1006993&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=8288289832073425974&hvtargid=kwd-299433375070&hydadcr=17608_1817743&keywords=concurrency%20in%20action&qid=1641474530&sr=8-1), and its something wrong with it (or I had a long day).

```
#include <atomic>
class spinlock 
{
    std::atomic_flag flag;
public:
    spinlock() : flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {}
    void lock() {
        while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
    }
    void unlock(){
        flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
};

spinlock sl;
void f() 
{
    std::lock_guard lc(sl);
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

So this is enough for `std::lock_guard` to acquire it, but I have a compilation error.

*error C2280: 'std::atomic_flag::atomic_flag(const std::atomic_flag &)': attempting to reference a deleted function*

To be honest I dont see how `spinlock() : flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {}` is calling a copy constructor.
I use **VS2022** with **C++20**  standard and ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT is defined as following:

```
#define ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT \
    {}
```

Is this book example broken, or am I donning something wrong?

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't see why this was particularly necessary here but edited anyway..

Comment: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT

Comment: a [mre] is necessary to avoid us having to do extra work to get your code to compile then finding that actually the bug you were asking about was not in the code posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) can only be used as follows:

```
std::atomic_flag v = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
```

It is unspecified if

```
flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT)
```

will work. If visual studio defines `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` as `{}` then your code is presumably ending up creating an `std::atomic_flag` with `{}` then calling the deleted copy constructor of `flag`.

If you're using c++20 you can simply remove the `flag` initialiser as `std::atomic_flag`'s default constructor now initialises to `false`.

Without c++20 I think the only way to do this according to the standard is to use an inline initialiser:

```
class spinlock 
{
    std::atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
public:
    void lock() {
        while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
    }
    void unlock(){
        flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
};
```

Comment: Actually, you can use `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` in an initializer list, like this: `spinlock() : flag ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` (assuming the macro is defined as `{}`, that is).

Comment: @AdrianMole if `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` is defined to `{}` then yes you can but the only way guaranteed by the standard is to initialise by assignment (at least according to cppreference)

Comment: Yep - things get sticky between C++17 and C++20.